Laravel valet Permission issue
Warning: opendir(/Users/apple/Desktop/programs/ideas): Failed to open directory: Operation not permitted in /Users/apple/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/Valet/Server.php on line 167
i have valet installed and running, after updating my system from OSX Monterey 12.6 to 12.7, i started getting the above error, despite following all sugested solution online i cant seem to pass this,
when i pink my project (ideas.test) from terminal it seems to work but cant open it in browser
tried using, XAMP, HERD and other development servers as well still no luck.
tried the chmod -r 777 as well
uninstalled and install
this is day 5

i finally found the solution.
first, i uninstalled and removed all valet dependencies, as follows
valet uninstall --force
sudo brew services stop nginx
sudo brew services stop php70
sudo brew services stop dnsmasq
brew uninstall nginx
brew uninstall php@8.3
brew uninstall php@8.0
brew uninstall dnsmasq
rm -rf ~/.valet
rm /usr/local/bin/valet

then I did a fresh "Herd" installation and the permission issue went off.
